# Oracle sql different id but same values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
BOOKID | TITLE                | SUBTITLE
1000   |The Lord of the Rings |The Return of the King 
1001   |The Lord of the Rings |The Two Towers 
1002   |The Lord of the Rings |The Two Towers 
1003   |The Lord of the Rings |The Fellowship of the Ring
```

I use this code to get the bookid of the three different parts but only once.

```
select BOOKID
from BOOKS
WHERE TITLE = 'The Lord of the Rings' AND 
SUBTITLE IN (SELECT SUBTITLE FROM BOOKS GROUP BY SUBTITLE HAVING COUNT(*) < 2);
```

I need for example these three id: 1000, 1001, 1003.
But I get four or two if the COUNT(*) = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` in the main query,

```
select     min(BOOKID) as BOOKID
from       BOOKS
where      TITLE = 'The Lord of the Rings'
group by   SUBTITLE
```

This is guaranteed to have exactly one row per unique `SUBTITLE` (the min `BOOKID`). For your example you get 1000, 1001, 1003 as required.

Answer (score 0):

you could go about it differently: select min(book_id) as book id from books where title = '...' group by TITLE,SUBTITLE

Your original way, techically the subtitle is found twice... the subset is a distinct list but two rows in the table match the criteria, that's why you get 4.  When doing count(*) == 1, only 2 rows meet that criteria so that's why.